# Custom progress bar for <audio> and <progress> HTML5 elements

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, progress

I am mind boggled at working out how to create a custom seekbar for an audio player using the  tag and simple Javascript.

Current Code:

```
    <script>
  function play() {
   document.getElementById('player').play();
  }

  function pause() {
   document.getElementById('player').pause();
  }
</script>


<audio src="sample.mp3" id="player"></audio>  
<button onClick="javascript:play()" >Play</button>
<button onClick="javascript:pause()" >Pause</button>
<progress id="seekbar"></progress>
```

Would it be possible to link the progress bar so that when i play a song the progress is shown?

Comment: HTML5 and stuff like `onClick="javascript:play()"` is an atrocious pairing.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using the [timeupdate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) event of the audio tag. You receive this event every time the position of the playback is updated. Then, you can update your progress bar using the `currentTime` and `duration` properties of the audio element.

You can see a working example in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbalsas/DCE6N/4/)

Comment: Is it possible to have this code as regular javascript rather than JQuery?

Comment: It now checks every 250ms for the new time. Is it possible to do this a little faster so the bar fills more smoothly?

Comment: Btw, this is one of the 1000s of reasons not to link to W3fools.com, that link is dead.

Comment: @ValentinKlinghammer I've updated the link to point to the mediaevents mdn page instead.

Comment: @Luc Check out `Vladislav Filonov` answer below.

Comment: when i am using the `timeupdate` the audio is playing but lagging ??? what is the solution ?

Answer (score 14):

If you want smooth progress bar,try somethink like that

HTML:

```
<div class="hp_slide">
     <div class="hp_range"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hp_slide{
    width:100%;
    background:white;
    height:25px;
}
.hp_range{
    width:0;
    background:black;
    height:25px;
}
```

JS:

```
var player = document.getElementById('player');    
player.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    var currentTime = player.currentTime;
    var duration = player.duration;
    $('.hp_range').stop(true,true).animate({'width':(currentTime +.25)/duration*100+'%'},250,'linear');
});
```

Pretty rough,but works

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple vanilla example:

```js
const url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Webern_-_Sehr_langsam.ogg";
const audio = new Audio(url);
const playBtn = document.querySelector("button");
const progressEl = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');
let mouseDownOnSlider = false;

audio.addEventListener("loadeddata", () => {
  progressEl.value = 0;
});
audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", () => {
  if (!mouseDownOnSlider) {
    progressEl.value = audio.currentTime / audio.duration * 100;
  }
});
audio.addEventListener("ended", () => {
  playBtn.textContent = "▶️";
});

playBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  audio.paused ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
  playBtn.textContent = audio.paused ? "▶️" : "⏸️";
});

progressEl.addEventListener("change", () => {
  const pct = progressEl.value / 100;
  audio.currentTime = (audio.duration || 0) * pct;
});
progressEl.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
  mouseDownOnSlider = true;
});
progressEl.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
  mouseDownOnSlider = false;
});
```

```css
button {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<button>▶️</button>
<input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" step="1">
```

The approach is to use an `input[type="range"]` slider to reflect the progress and allow the user to seek through the track. When the range changes, set the `audio.currentTime` attribute, using the slider as a percent (you could also adjust the `max` attribute of the slider to match the `audio.duration`).

In the other direction, I update the slider's progress on `timeupdate` event firing.

One corner case is that if the user scrolls around with their mouse down on the slider, the `timeupdate` event will keep firing, causing the progress to hop around between wherever the user's cursor is hovering and the current audio progress. I use a boolean and the `mousedown`/`mouseup` events on the slider to prevent this from happening.

---

See also [JavaScript - HTML5 Audio / custom player's seekbar and current time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49814828/javascript-html5-audio-custom-players-seekbar-and-current-time/70638724#70638724) for an extension of this code that displays the time.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use the `progress` element, it's a shitty element (for now) and styling it is a huge pain in... well it's boring (look at a little project I made, [look at it](https://github.com/Calvein/Simple-uploader/blob/gh-pages/style.css#L182-L214) (and it's juste webkit/moz)).

Anyway, you should read the doc on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video), it's very easy and with a lot of examples. What you are looking for is the `currentTime` attribute, here a little snippet :

```
var audio = document.querySelector('#player')
audio.currentTime = 60 // will go to the 60th second
```

So what you need is to use the cross-multiplication (`div` is the element you use as a progress bar) : 
Where I clicked on `div` | THE TIME I WANT TO KNOW
————————————————————————————————————————
Total length of `div`    | The total time of my video/audio (`audio.seekable.end()`)