# Audio Progress Bar html5 with interaction

Tags: jquery, html, audio

Hey i need creat a simple player in html 5, i create de control, play, pause,

but i need a progress bar with interation

this example is a interarion bar, but i need click and this move to music time

http://jsfiddle.net/LQqGS/3/

```
 $('.clickable').bind('click', function (ev) {
                var $div = $(ev.target);
                var $display = $div.find('.display');

                var offset = $div.offset();
                var x = ev.clientX - offset.left;

                $('.progress').width(x);
            });

            $("#pause").click(function() {
                audioElement.pause();
            });
```

Comment: Nobody here is going to write you the whole player... but if you put the playing audio and everything else needed into your example, we'd be more than happy to help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom progress bar for <audio> and <progress> HTML5 elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314345/custom-progress-bar-for-audio-and-progress-html5-elements)

Answer (score 0):

You already did most of the work. What you need to do now is to change the `currentTime`  value for your audio player. It's a value in seconds.

Since you already have the X position of your click, you can divide that by the width of your progress bar to get the percentage of the song that should be played.

You have the `duration` property for the audio element, which returns the length of the currently playing audio file, in seconds.

```
var duration = player.duration;
var ratio = X / progressBar.width(); 
var newCurrentTime = ratio * duration.
player.currentTime = newCurrentTime;
```

That's just a quick example, replace the variable names with their appropriate values.

Let's say that your progress bar is exactly 100px wide, and that you are calculating that the click occured at 50px, the ratio would be `50/100`, so `0.5`. Multiply that by the total duration of the audio track, and you will get the new duration to set.